# Wired headset circuit

Tags: microphone

I'm trying to understand how mobile phone headsets work. I figured out that the electret mic gets supplied with 2.7V by the phone.

Opening a headset revealed the following PCB:
[image]

I looked and measured and came up with the following circuit:
[image]

Shouldn't there be at least one cap in series with the mic?

Answer (score 6):

Electret microphones need a biasing voltage to operate: The 2.7 Volts you measured.

If there is a capacitor in series with the microphone, this would block DC, thus there would be no biasing voltage.

If the preamplifier / buffer inside the phone body needs the bias voltage removed, a capacitor would be placed in that part of the circuit, past the bias voltage provision stage, i.e. on the PCB inside the mobile phone handset.

Answer (score 0):

The diode is there to clamp the voltage to 2.7V, it's a zener.  The two caps are bypassing any AC on the line, one at low freq, the other at high freq.

Comment: You *want* the AC on the line - it's the microphone signal!

Comment: @ConnorWolf - The caps could be removing non-audio frequencies.